# beautifulsoup not working after exception raised

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

my program was working fine for several days but yesterday after this exception was catched:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

now every time i try to run my code i keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

here is the line where this error comes from:

```
t = soup.find("h1", class_="title").get_text()
```

i don't think the problem comes from my code because it was working just fine for several days. is there a button to restart python :p (just joking)

i should mention that when i run my code on my local machine everything is fine, but on the server i keep getting AttributeError

**EDIT:**

- when i printed soup.body i got None as a result
- when i printed soup.title i got the actual title of the page
- the html is correct

Comment: probably your target page's HTML changed and `<h1 class="title">` is no longer present...

Comment: @MattDMo nope, i already checked, it's still the same

Comment: is there supposed to be an underscore `_` after `class`?

Comment: @MattDMo yep, it's in the docs

Comment: what does the html look like?

Comment: You will need to show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to help debug your code and data.

Comment: Also, I know you were joking, but if the target you're scraping is archived on the Wayback Machine, you might actually be able to run your code "in the past" by pointing at the archive from last week. Of course that doesn't help if you're trying to get up-to-date data; in that case, you'll need to figure out how to parse their up-to-date pages.

Comment: Anyway, @MattDMo is almost certainly right. The error was probably because you hit them while they were updating their servers, and since the update the HTML format they generate has probably changed.

Comment: @abarnert i think i'm getting closer to the answer ... i found that when logging soup.body i get None as an output ! any ideas why?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham when logging soup.body i get None as an output ! any ideas why?

Comment: @MattDMo when logging soup.body i get None as an output ! any ideas why?

Comment: @RachidO.: Presumably because the top-level element has no direct child tag named `body` (or it's broken in such a way that the parser doesn't place `body` directly under the top-level element). If you would actually provide the information people are asking for (again, see the MCVE link), people could help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by specifing a BeautifulSoup parser,This is because of the differences in BeautifulSoup parsers.

```
BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html5lib")
```

`html5lib` cannot get the body from this particular html so i changed it to

```
BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: post the complete stack trace, otherwise one cannot tell what's the chain of functions where the problem occured from top to bottom call.

Therefore, I can only speculate: since `soup.body` returns `None`, probably `.find` does something similar that returns `None` as well, otherwise you would not get exception that essentially says "there is no get_text() method in None".

Clearly, that's the intermediate reason here, but the question is what caused this error (`.body()` or `.find()` returning `None`) in turn and that's hard without full stack trace.

Answer (score -3):

I think it is related to the network.Because it can not connect to the server so you can not get its html files, which means if you use a function like **find**, it will throw an error.

Comment: **This is so blatantly wrong.** If BS couldn't get the file it would error out much earlier than this call.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Almost certainly true… but given that the OP never told us anything about how he retrieved the file, much less showed us any code, you can't completely rule out the possibility that he wrote a function that returns `''` on failure or something silly.